# Need a confirmation regarding persisting a referenced (embedded) object using jdo+datanucleus

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

Hi I am persisting a class with a collection(List) of interface.

I see this on link 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/jdo/orm/embedded.html#Collection 
and it says "Embedded elements cannot have inheritance (this may be allowed in the future)"

So, how to persist such objects?

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue a few hours ago, hope it helps others starting with jdo/datanucleus.

As stated in the [current docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/interfaces.html), the only way to persist a collection of interfaces is through an [unidirectional join table](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/one_to_many_list.html#join_uni). It's not possible to directly embed the objects implementing the interface.

```java
@PersistenceCapable
public class SomeClass {
    @Join
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="implementation-classes", value="ImplementingClass")
    private List<SomeInterface> myList;

    // this list would be embedded
    private List<SomeOtherClass> myOtherList;
    // ...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public interface SomeInterface {
    // ...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class ImplementingClass implements SomeInterface {
    // ...
}

@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly="true")
public class SomeOtherClass {
    // ...
}
```